# Verify if the value of input already exists in array

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

i have a issue, i have two inputs then and i can't permit the user save this edit if the two values is equals.

my state who contains a data from db

```
const [doctorRegisters, setDoctorResgisters] = useState<any>([]);
```

inside this array i contain this

```
[{"__typename": "DoctorMedicalRegister", "counsil": "CRM", "id": "141", "isMainRegister": true, "register": "1234567/RS"}, {"__typename": "DoctorMedicalRegister", "counsil": "CRM", "id": "153", "isMainRegister": false, "register": "1234567/RS"}]
```

and i need compare two register who if is equal, i cant permit user save he save just is different

here is a code who i try fix this

```
  const isEquals = () => {
    doctorRegisters.map((item: any) => {
      if (item.register) {
        doctorRegisters.map((item2: any) => {
          if (item2.register) {
            if (item.register === item2.register) {
              console.log('iguais')
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };
```

but this work only for dont edited values i need verify when this value is changed in input in this case i only verify in db this values is equals

here is my handle change

```
  const handleEditRegisterCrm = (crm: string, id: number) => {
    setDoctorResgisters(
      doctorRegisters.map((item: any) => {
        if (item && Number(item.id) == id) {
          item.register = `${crm}/${item.register?.split('/')[1] || ''}`;
        }
        return item;
      }),
    );
  };
```

Comment: What does "dont edited values" means ?

Comment: `Array.prototype.indexOf()` can also work as a way to check if the value exists within an array. In this case, you can do something like `if (doctorRegisters.indexOf(value) !==-1) ...`

Comment: @ElenaAlexeenko Probably unedited values/checks once and doesnt care for edited values

Comment: @ElenaAlexeenko "dont edited values" is a values when i change this inside my input when i edit this values and save again this dont validate the new value just a value who have before this

Comment: @Archigan yes i tried use indexOf but didn't work in this case i don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
const handleEditRegisterCrm = (crm: string, id: number) => {
  if (!doctorRegisters.some((doctorRegister) => doctorRegister.register.includes(registerToCompare)) {
    setDoctorRegisters(
      doctorRegisters.map((item: any) => {
        if (item && Number(item.id) == id) {
          item.register = `${crm}/${item.register?.split('/')[1] || ''}`;
        }
        return item;
      }),
    );
  } 
};
```

Remember you should keep track of the `registerToCompare` in order to find if it's already inserted in the `doctorRegisters` list. I'm assuming you can obtain that value from the your `handleChange` function.